# How to minimize all windows except Conky?

Tags: lubuntu, conky, minimize

I would like to minimize all open windows with the exception of the Conky app, because the default minimize-all makes Conky info on screen disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script minallwin.lua (made in the lua language)

```
-- shebang for running in several platforms
--  #!/bin/sh
--  _=[[
--  exec lua "$0" "$@"
--  ]]

f = assert (io.popen ("wmctrl -lp"))
for line in f:lines() do
    w_id = string.sub(line,1,10)
    i, j = string.find(line,"conky")
    if (i == nil) then
        os.execute("xdotool windowminimize " .. w_id)
    end
end -- for loop
f:close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option named `own_window_type` if you set it to `desktop` conky is not going to be minimized:

```
nano ~/.conkyrc
```

and add:

```
own_window_type desktop
```

save the file and done.